# query received same email multiple times

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, data, data-views

I have a data issue where we have duplicate emails under different Subscriberkey.
I'm trying to build a query now to check how many of this duplicate emails have received the same email multiple times.
I have a Data Extension that looks like this so I have all the duplicated emails.

```
Email Address      SubscriberKey
john@example.com    1234567890
john@example.com    0987654321
john@example.com    4567890123
```

I wrote this query to return a list of all the emails that the email address has received more than once, along with the count of those sends but I'm getting 0 results and can't figure out where the issue is.

```
    SELECT
    s.SubscriberKey,
    s.JobID,
    s.BatchID,
    s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID,
    COUNT(*) AS NumSends
FROM
    _Sent s
INNER JOIN
    _Job j
ON
    s.JobID = j.JobID
WHERE
    s.EventDate >= '2022-12-01'
    AND s.SubscriberKey IN (SELECT EmailAddress FROM [DuplicatesDE])
GROUP BY
    s.SubscriberKey,
    s.JobID,
    s.BatchID,
    s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: I think you're selecting the wrong field from the DuplicatesDE?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the IN statement should be pulling SubscriberKey instead of EmailAddress? Based on the layout of the Data Extension you provided with EmailAddress and SubscriberKey fields.

```
AND s.SubscriberKey IN (SELECT EmailAddress FROM [DuplicatesDE])
```

Use this instead?

```
AND s.SubscriberKey IN (SELECT SubscriberKey FROM [DuplicatesDE])
```